# compiling with -G flag leading to ptxas parsing error/syntax error

Tags: cuda, cuda-gdb

I am using a popular repo: [siboehm/SGEMM_CUDA](https://github.com/siboehm/SGEMM_CUDA).

When building without debugging: i.e.

```
mkdir build && cd build && \
cmake .. && cmake --build .
```

the program compiles, links and runs without error.
Important compilation commands used in the build process:

```
/usr/local/cuda-12.3/bin/nvcc \
-forward-unknown-to-host-compiler  \
-I/usr/local/cuda-12.3/include \
-I/home/jasneetsingh/Desktop/cuda_experiments/SGEMM_CUDA/src \
--generate-code=arch=compute_86,code=[compute_86,sm_86] \
-MD -MT CMakeFiles/sgemm.dir/src/runner.cu.o \
-MF CMakeFiles/sgemm.dir/src/runner.cu.o.d \
-x cu -c \
/home/jasneetsingh/Desktop/cuda_experiments/SGEMM_CUDA/src/runner.cu \
-o CMakeFiles/sgemm.dir/src/runner.cu.o
```

but when using debug i.e.

```
mkdir build && cd build && \
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug && \
cmake --build .
```

this error comes when executing the command (in CMake build):

```
/usr/local/cuda-12.3/bin/nvcc \
-forward-unknown-to-host-compiler  \
-I/usr/local/cuda-12.3/include \
-I/home/jasneetsingh/Desktop/cuda_experiments/SGEMM_CUDA/src \
-g \
--generate-code=arch=compute_86,code=[compute_86,sm_86] \
-G \
-src-in-ptx \
-MD -MT CMakeFiles/sgemm.dir/src/runner.cu.o \
-MF CMakeFiles/sgemm.dir/src/runner.cu.o.d \
-x cu -c \
/home/jasneetsingh/Desktop/cuda_experiments/SGEMM_CUDA/src/runner.cu \
-o CMakeFiles/sgemm.dir/src/runner.cu.o
```

```
    ptxas /tmp/tmpxft_00004480_00000000-6_runner.ptx, line 881; fatal : Parsing error near '': syntax error
    ptxas fatal : Ptx assembly aborted due to errors
    gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/sgemm.dir/build.make:90: CMakeFiles/sgemm.dir/src/runner.cu.o] Error 255
    gmake[2]: Leaving directory '/home/jasneetsingh/Desktop/cuda_experiments/SGEMM_CUDA/build'
```

It must have something to do with `-G` flag.

My system info:

- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
- The CUDA compiler identification is NVIDIA 12.3.107
- CUDA: `/usr/local/cuda-12.3` (found version "12.3")

Comment: So don't build with debugging....

Comment: According to my testing the error depends on both inclusion of `-G` as well as inclusion of `-src-in-ptx`.  The `-src-in-ptx` [switch](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#source-in-ptx-src-in-ptx) should have no functional effect on the compiled code (i.e. the SASS that gets executed) so it should be safe to drop that switch as a workaround.  I have filed NVIDIA internal bug 4510055 for this report.  Or as already indicated, you could drop the `-G` switch, which enables/disables generation of debug device code.

Comment: thanks @RobertCrovella my objective is to understood how threads are accessing respective rows and columns of the matrix to understand the optimizations.. if i drop `-G` and use `-lineinfo`  flag, then, when using _cuda-gdb_, i am unable to set breakpoints inside the kernel. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes.  Keep the `-G` flag and drop the `-src-in-ptx` flag.

Comment: this works @RobertCrovella thanks a lot for really quick reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated my problem was inability set up breakpoints inside the kernel, since I was unable to compile with `-G` flag using CMAKE. Comment from @robertcrovella solved this problem.
i.e. I removed the `-src-in-ptx` and compilation was successful and breakpoints were being placed in cuda kernel